# OnChange event doesn't seem to get hooked correctly

Tags: javascript

Probable something really stupid but suppose I have 2 elements that match $('[id$=_product_id]') why are the change events not matched properly?

```
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;

$('[id$=_product_id]').each(function(idx, elem) {
recordId = elem.id.match(numberPattern)
productId = elem.value;         
console.log(recordId);

    $("#client_order_order_lines_attributes_" + recordId + "_product_id").on("change", function(e) {      
      console.log(recordId);
    })
});
```

I created a fiddle that demonstrates this http://jsfiddle.net/hLYpE/1/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *need* to declare those variables, that's the danger of implicit globals.

```
var recordId = elem.id.match(numberPattern);
var productId = elem.value;
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/hLYpE/4/

Comment: That is indeed working, will definitely need to read up on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should change the code adding the var in front of the name of the variables:

```
var numberPattern = /\d+/g;

$('[id$=_product_id]').each(function(idx, elem) {
var recordId = elem.id.match(numberPattern),
    productId = elem.value;         
console.log(recordId);

    $("#client_order_order_lines_attributes_" + recordId + "_product_id").on("change", function(e) {      
      console.log(recordId);
    })
});
```